# Complex image manipulation using HTML5/JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, konvajs

Is it possible to easily replicate the "put your face in this photo and share it with your friends" functionality (as seen on many sites, eg. [this one](http://www.faceinhole.com)) using only HTML5 and/or JavaScript?

Every other site I've seen doing this uses Flash, but it would be good to get it running across all mobile devices.

I've taken a look at [Konva](https://github.com/konvajs/konva) (the successor to KinectJS) but I'm still not entirely sure this can be done using only HTML and JS.

Comment: I'm certain it can be done using HTML / CSS. Layer a image with a transparent "hole" over a photo of the person't face...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use fabric.js to do that, your example is fabric.

here is of your solution :) - 15 min coding
http://jsfiddle.net/d9a9n5h7/

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
    <canvas id="imageCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas> 
    <a id="imageSaver" href="#">Save image</a>
</div>
<img id="bgImg" scr="base 64 "/>
```

Here:
  base 64 transformed image (check fiddle)

declare fabric canvas:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('imageCanvas', {
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(240,240,240)'
});
canvas.setWidth(300);
canvas.setHeight(300);

canvas.add(setBgImg());
```

set image with missing face:

```
function setBgImg()
{
    var imgElement = document.getElementById('bgImg')
    return fabricImg = new fabric.Image(
                imgElement, {
                    selectable: !1,
                    evented: !1,
                    hasControls: !1,
                    hasBorders: !1
                });
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much! Never used Fabric before. I'll send you some rep when the site lets me as a way of thanks.

Comment: with pleasure and have fun

Comment: @Chuck Thanks mister, din't expect that.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was searching. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. It's simply combining two images and using saturation/brightness/hue/scale operations on one of them. A viable way would be to use a HTML canvas for this.